# Create-react-app fails to create app structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to use create-react-app to create a react app skeleton but this command miserably fails in between and ends up creating only half package.json and downloading not all node_modules

some such kind of half output

> npm install --save-dev --save-exact react-scripts failedarPerm extractEntry _ba

It doesn't fail at the same point always, i am running this on a linux server with CentOS 7 
Not getting whats wrong , any help is appreciated

Comment: Check your Node version `node --version`

Comment: Version is at 6.9

Comment: Well that's not the problem. Maybe the network access is restricted, can't fetch the packages?

Comment: It breaks half way , but all other npm commands are completing

Comment: Permissions issue to create the sub directory?

Comment: Running it under root so not probably

Comment: You are passing app name - `create-react-app myApp`, correct?

Comment: @Andy_D yes exactly I am calling it with a unique app name

Comment: Maybe there's a directory permission issue.